# Storing the type of a generic in an interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a generic interface like so:

```
interface A<T extends Object> {
  b: T;
}
```

Currently "b" is stored as an instance of T, however I would like to store the non-instanced version of T as a value within the interface.

My initial thought was to do something like this:

```
interface A<T extends Object> {
  b: typeof T;
}
```

However I don't think this is correct, nor is it allowed by the compiler.
Can this be done?

This below succeeds in what I want to achieve, however it does not enforce 'b' to the generic:

```
interface A<T extends Object> {
  b: Object;
}
```

Comment: "Non-instanced version of T" what does that mean? In your example you say `typeof T` but `T` is *already* a type. "This below succeeds in what I want to achieve" how? Huh? I'm sorry but I don't get this at all... are you asking how to make `b` itself be a parameterized type?

Comment: I'm still getting to grips with the terminology. I'm essentially trying to include the actual class T. I wanted to avoid inferring the generic type for the time being and was wondering if it could be achieved in a similar manner to above.

Comment: What's the point of `c` in this example?  It's invalid syntax, and seems like it's beside the point of your question.  Could you fix it if it needs to be there, or remove it if it doesn't?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/Na4Dpw) is what you're looking for?  Without a use case that shows how you intend to consume/produce a value of type `A<T>` it's hard to say.

Comment: @jcalz Cheers that accomplishes the task of providing the constraint perfectly! I'll remove `c` from the example also as its irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) to refer to the type of a class constructor.  It looks like this:

```
interface A<T extends object> {
    instance: T; 
    ctor: new (...args: any) => T; 
}
```

And here's an example of using it:

```
const aDate: A<Date> = {
    instance: new Date(),
    ctor: Date
} // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIB4AqyIA9IgAmAzsgPYBGAVhAmAHzIDeAsAFDKfKjFhwhIAXMkwBuZAHoJyftxC9+Sdl2R0yUYSAgB3ZAAoAdEbhQA5sWH8AngEpkAXkZj2AX3bsEZeWBkAROJDCGP6QjPbMylw8fAIQmjrIIRB6NgA0kZxqGokBEK6S0mQA1nBWQA)